# I have tried optimizing model parameters using optim() but I am getting the same parameters. How do i get the optimized parameters?

Tags: python, r, ode

Here I have modeled the Epidemic disease for which I am trying to optimize the parameters so that I can fit the model with the covid-19 data. The problem here is an I am not able to get the optimized parameters instead getting the same parameters. what should I fix here and get optimized parameters for my model? Please help me correcting the code.

```
library(deSolve)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2) 
library(ggpubr)

# Model Input


N <- 1380004385

p <- .87 #0.88689

initial_state_values <- c(S = N - 1, E = 0, A = 0, I = 1, T = 0, F = 0, R = 0)


parameters <- c(pie = .6782, mu = 0.0000391, beta =.89768, alpha = 0.24757, phi = 0.08, 
h = 1.08, mu_I = 0.06891, mu_T = 0.06891, gamma_I =  0.05090, 
gamma_T = 0.07048) #67446.82054)

time <- seq(1, 164, .1)
# Input function: Differential equation

SEAITFR_fn <- function(time, initial_state_values, parameters) {
  
  with(as.list(c(initial_state_values, parameters)), {
    N  <- S+E+A+I+T+F+R
    lamda <- beta/N * (A + I)
    dS <- pie - (lamda + mu) * S
    dE <- lamda * S - (alpha + mu) * E
    dA <- alpha * (1-p) * E - (mu + phi) * A
    dI <- alpha * p * E + phi * A -(h + gamma_I + mu_I + mu) * I
    dT <- h * I - (gamma_T + mu_T) * T
    dF <- mu_I * I + mu_T * T
    dR <- gamma_I * I + gamma_T * T - mu * R
    
    
    return(list(c(dS, dE, dA, dI, dT, dF, dR)))
    
  })
  
}

output <- as.data.frame(ode(y = initial_state_values,  
                            
                            times = time,             
                            func = SEAITFR_fn,             
                            parms = parameters)       
                        
)
#output
output$total_prevalence <- output$I + output$T
#output$total_prevalence 



# Distance Function

SEAITFR_SSQ <- function(parameters, data) {  
  
  
  
  output <- as.data.frame(ode(y = initial_state_values,  # vector of initial state 
                           
                              times = time,             # vector of times
                              func = SEAITFR_fn,             
                              parms = parameters)      
                         
                          )
  
  
  data <- na.omit(data)  
  
 
  deltas_square <- (output$total_prevalence[output$time %in% data$time] - 
                    data$new_cases)^2                             
  SSQ   <- sum(deltas_square)
  
  return(SSQ)
  
}
# Real world data
covid_19_data <- read_excel("covid.xlsx")
covid_19_data


#Optimization

optimised <- optim(par = c(pie =.6782, mu = 0.0000391, beta = 0.88689, alpha = 0.24757, phi = 0.08, 
                              h = 1.08, mu_I = 0.06891, mu_T = 0.06891, gamma_I =  0.05090, 
                              gamma_T = 0.07048),      # these are the starting beta 
                                           # and gamma that will be fed 
                                             # first, into SSQ_fn
                    fn = SEAITFR_SSQ,
                    data = covid_19_data  # this argument comes under "..." 
                                         # "Further arguments to be passed to fn a
                   )

optimised 


optimised_model <- as.data.frame(ode(y = initial_state_values, 
                                     times = time, func = SEAITFR_fn, parms = optimised$par))

# Optimised_model
optimised_model$prevalence <- optimised_model$I + optimised_model$T
#optimised_model$prevalence

# Plotting
plot2 <- ggplot() + geom_line(data = optimised_model, 
                              aes(x = time, y = prevalence)) + 
  geom_point(data = covid_19_data, aes(x = time, y = new_cases), colour = "red" ) +
  xlab("Times(days)") + ylab("No. of infection") + labs(title = 
        paste("Calibration of SIR model with optimised value ")) + ylim(0,30000)
 
plot2
```

Comment: Covid-19 data is fraudulent, meaningless. Thus it would not be surprising if an appropriate solution can not be found, or if the fit is good enough, that the parameters are meaningless or that the extrapolation does not even reach the predictive quality of the weather forecast.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get your model to run with `different parameters` based on the output. Also, I have used `maximum likelihood estimation` and it is working just fine with the `covid data`

Answer (score 0):

```r
require(deSolve)

SIR_fn <- function(time, state, parameters) {
  
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    N  <- S+I+R
    dS <- -beta*S*I/N
    dI <- beta*S*I/N-gamma*I
    dR <- gamma*I
    return(list(c(dS, dI, dR)))
    
  })
  
}

SIR_SSQ <- function(parameters, dat) {  # parameters must contain beta & gamma
  # calculate model output using your SIR function with ode()
  result <- as.data.frame(ode(y = initial_state_values  # vector of initial state 
                              # values, with named elements
                              , times = times             # vector of times
                              , func = SIR_fn             # your predefined SIR function
                              , parms = parameters)       # the parameters argument
                          # entered with SIR_SSQ()
  )
  
  # SSQ calculation: needs the dat argument (the observed data you are fitting to)
  # assumes the data you are fitting to has a column "I"
  
  # select only complete cases, i.e. rows with no NAs, from the dataframe
  dat <- na.omit(dat)  
  
  # select elements where results$time is in dat$time
  deltas2 <- (result$I[result$time %in% dat$time] - dat$I)^2                             
  SSQ     <- sum(deltas2)
  return(SSQ)
  
}


flu_dat <- read.csv("flu.csv")
head(flu_dat, 10)

#         time     I
#      1     1 16928
#      2     2 21389
#      3     3 20006
#      4     4 21368
#      5     5 25349
#      6     6 21405
#      7     7 17662
#      8     8 17492
#      9     9 18361
#      10   10 20951
     
initial_state_values <- c(S = 100000, I = 1, R = 0)

# choose values to start your optimisation
beta_start  <- 0.1
gamma_start <- 0.1

# times - dense timesteps for a more detailed solution
times <- seq(from = 0, to = 107, by = 0.01)

# optim
# you will need to run the cells to assign your functions first

optimised <- optim(
  par = c(beta = beta_start
          , gamma = gamma_start)      # these are the starting beta
  # and gamma that will be fed
  # first, into SSQ_fn
  ,
  fn = SIR_SSQ
  ,
  dat = flu_dat  # this argument comes under "..."
  # "Further arguments to be passed to fn and gr"
)

optimised #have a look at the model output

# $par
#       beta      gamma 
#       0.40487383 0.01637813 
#       
#       $value
#       [1] 25002879441
#       
#       $counts
#       function gradient 
#       81       NA 
#       
#       $convergence
#       [1] 0
#       
#       $message
#       NULL
#       
#      
#        optimised$par
#       beta      gamma 
#       0.40487383 0.01637813 

opt_mod <- as.data.frame(ode(y = initial_state_values  # named vector of initial
                             # state values
                             , times = times            # vector of times
                             ,  func = SIR_fn           # your predefined SIR function
                             , parms = optimised$par))


## plot your optimised model output, with the epidemic data using ggplot ##
require(ggplot2)

opt_plot <- ggplot()
opt_plot <- opt_plot + geom_point(aes(x = time, y = I)
                                  , colour = "red"
                                  ,size = 3
                                  , shape  = "x" 
                                  , data = flu_dat)
opt_plot <- opt_plot + geom_line(aes(x = time, y = I)
                                 , colour = "blue"
                                 , data   = opt_mod)
opt_plot

flu_dat
# time     I
# 1      1 16928
# 2      2 21389
# 3      3 20006
# 4      4 21368
# 5      5 25349
# 6      6 21405
# 7      7 17662
# 8      8 17492
# 9      9 18361
# 10    10 20951
# 11    11 23042
# 12    12 24914
# 13    13 25268
# 14    14 19019
# 15    15 19456
# 16    16 23693
# 17    17 26499
# 18    18 27867
# 19    19 30981
# 20    20 31917
# 21    21 25968
# 22    22 30676
# 23    23 36208
# 24    24 34426
# 25    25 40356
# 26    26 45353
# 27    27 41359
# 28    28 40409
# 29    29 40057
# 30    30 45980
# 31    31 51488
# 32    32 55588
# 33    33 51841
# 34    34 45549
# 35    35 49580
# 36    36 44162
# 37    37 60755
# 38    38 59740
# 39    39 62567
# 40    40 67859
# 41    41 60038
# 42    42 59085
# 43    43 58793
# 44    44 67427
# 45    45 67635
# 46    46 77102
# 47    47 71672
# 48    48 62470
# 49    49 60716
# 50    50 61477
# 51    51 64239
# 52    52 71915
# 53    53 68511
# 54    54 73208
# 55    55 65375
# 56    56 54864
# 57    57 55947
# 58    58 65785
# 59    59 71832
# 60    60 67599
# 61    61 67911
# 62    62 57839
# 63    63 46269
# 64    64 44567
# 65    65 57283
# 66    66 54433
# 67    67 59481
# 68    68 58322
# 69    69 54449
# 70    70 46369
# 71    71 48733
# 72    72 46910
# 73    73 56811
# 74    74 51742
# 75    75 64764
# 76    76 46790
# 77    77 41181
# 78    78 36484
# 79    79 45034
# 80    80 47393
# 81    81 44087
# 82    82 48253
# 83    83 43653
# 84    84 34510
# 85    85 36432
# 86    86 39979
# 87    87 45520
# 88    88 45120
# 89    89 46929
# 90    90 45414
# 91    91 34787
# 92    92 35138
# 93    93 41677
# 94    94 40951
# 95    95 43781
# 96    96 50129
# 97    97 43192
# 98    98 31511
# 99    99 23545
# 100  100 26845
# 101  101 33895
# 102  102 36066
# 103  103 47439
# 104  104 41003
# 105  105 34305
# 106  106 33842
# 107  107 39385
```

Comment: Original code formatting was broken and is now completely changed. The code has nevertheless some flaws: use of  `read.csv`, but data are just listed at the end. The code contains comments, but no textual explanation. It would be great if the original answerer or someone else could improve this.